# What attributes does bgcolor support

Tags: html, colors

The `bgcolor` tag takes different words and changes the color.

What actually happens? Does it take the ASCII values?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Background Color </title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="Daniel">
    </body>
</html>
```

When I assign random words to the `bgcolor` tag, it applies some kinda color. How does it work?

Comment: Insist upon using CSS. Don't use such HTML attributes.

Comment: @Daniel_V : Many of such HTML attributes are deprecated (or at least about to be deprecated), their usage is highly discouraged and they're liable to be removed in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By taking a screenshot of the page rendered by your code, and selecting the rendered pink-ish color in Photoshop, you can see that it's `#da00e0`.

`DAniEl`, only A-F and 0-9 are kept, and the others are zeroed.

I'm pretty sure if you use `bgcolor="Cyrille"` you'll have plain red (`#C00000`).

(Edit: actually, `Cyrille` gives `#c000e0`)

By the way, you shouldn't even be using this `bgColor` attribute. CSS is here for one reason!

Comment: Thank you. I'm just learning, am just trying those tags. :)